# how to write test scenarios from requirements?

Tags: bdd, specflow

When test call produces PolicyInput.XML where the TName="firstcall" the TValue on this item is as follows:
A 20 character string
Characters 1 & 2 contain the A2A01 value from the Experian response, with any blank space padded to the left
Characters 5 & 6 contain the CBD01 value from the Experian response, with any blank space padded to the left
Character 14 contains the GFA01 value from the Experian response
Characters 15 & 16 contain the BDDF11 value from the Experian response, with any blank space padded to the left
Character 17 contains the A2B01 value from the Experian response

Could any one explain me how to write scenario in a correct way

Answer (score 0):

Scenarios are basically examples of the business description of what should happen. They describe the journey from a starting state through a process to your expected outcome.

This list of information yuou have suplied is far too low level and also not decribing a process at all, you are basically missing out all of the information about how the test call was made in order to receive a result with the right information in it.

You should be focusing on many different examples, what information would you need to send to the call to get the results back that you expect, and what this information means (ie. its business description) rather than low level field names,

e.g.

```
Given I have a new client
When we process their information
Then we can see this was a first call

Given I have a returning client 
When we process their information
Then this shouldnt be a first call
```